# How can I retrieve the selected date value from datepicker jQuery UI in order to trigger something

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

As the title mentions, I want to update my page with data in accordance with selected date in jQuery UI datepicker. So i need to retrieve the current date value if no date is selected or retrieve the selected date data and crush the current date value, so I can dynamically show things on the page regarding the selected date.

Here is my code for the datepicker so far :

```
var date_choisie;

$( function() {
    $("#calendrier").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        // console.log(selectedDate); //Selected date
        date_choisie = selectedDate; //My attempt to put selectedDate in date_choisie
        }
    })
    //set date as current by default
    $("#calendrier").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

    //get date in a variable
    date_choisie = $('#calendrier').datepicker('getDate');
    date_choisie = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date_choisie);

    // console.log(date_choisie); //2020-09-20
} );
```

So I need to be able to get `selectedDate` in `date_choisie` (maybe I should `return selectedDate`)

After this I will pass `date_choisie` to my PHP file by using ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url : 'http://planning-ilm.atwebpages.com/userPlanning/'+ date_choisie,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        let semaine = document.createTextNode('Sem du ' + data.datecourante.mday + '/' + data.datecourante.mon + '/' + data.datecourante.year);
        $("#sem")[0].appendChild(semaine);
        showplannings(data.datecourante, data.message);
    }
})
```

The URL will call the following php function :

```
 function getUserPlanning($url){
        // Function used to get the user planning
        $today = getdate(); // This is the line i will change with the selected date

        // Searching for monday, if the selected date is not monday
        if($today ['weekday'] !== "Monday"){
            $monday = getdate(strtotime("last Monday")); //This is the line i will change with the selected date
            
            // We get everything in an array
            $dayMonthYear = dayMonthYearOfDate($monday);

            // Concatenation in string
            $dayMonthYearString = $dayMonthYear['day']. ' ' . $dayMonthYear['month']. ' ' . $dayMonthYear['year'];
        
            // We get every day of the week in array
            $theWeek = currentWeek($dayMonthYearString);

            return $error = json_encode([
                'status' => 'ok',
                'datecourante' => $monday, // Here is the monday of the selected day
                'message' => getHisPlanning($url[1], $theWeek)
            ]);
        }else{
            $dayMonthYear = dayMonthYearOfDate($today);
            $dayMonthYearString = $dayMonthYear['day']. ' ' . $dayMonthYear['month']. ' ' . $dayMonthYear['year'];
            // On a la semaine actuelle
            $theWeek = currentWeek($dayMonthYearString);

            
            return $error = json_encode([
                'status' => 'ok',
                'datecourante' => $today, // Here is the monday of the selected day
                'message' => getHisPlanning($url[1], $theWeek)
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Here are the functions used in getUserPlanning

```
function dayMonthYearOfDate($dateTostring){
        // Fonction permettant de retourner le jour, le mois et l'année sous forme de tableau
        $jour = $dateTostring['mday'];
        $mois = $dateTostring['month'];
        $annee = $dateTostring['year'];

        $dateofDay = ['day' => $jour, 'month' => $mois, 'year' => $annee];
        
        return $dateofDay;
    }
```

```
function currentWeek($currentDate){
        // Fonction permettant de retourner tous les jours de la semaine courante en prenant un string
        $monday = strtotime($currentDate);
        $tuesday = strtotime("next Tuesday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $wednesday = strtotime("next Wednesday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $thursday = strtotime("next Thursday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $friday = strtotime("next Friday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $saturday = strtotime("next Saturday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $sunday = strtotime("next Sunday", strtotime($currentDate));

        $week = [$monday, $tuesday, $wednesday, $thursday, $friday, $saturday, $sunday];
        return $week;
    }
```

By using getUserPlanning i can retrieve the selected date which is registered in data.datecourante

Comment: How are you calling the `$.ajax` - on some kind of click ?

Comment: Hello, actually right now no. But i want it to get triggered whenever the user selects a date in datepicker

Comment: You want to call ajax as soon as the user selects the date. then you can move you ajax call inside the onSelect function and it should send the select date.

Comment: Ok but what about the date by default?

Comment: you want to call ajax on date by default as well ? like as soon as the page loads ? and you want to call ajax on different date selection ?

Comment: Yes that is what i want. Bassically i need to show the date selected on screen and the current date if nothing is selected. Right now its only showing the current date

Comment: show the date on screen and also call ajax ?

Comment: If nothing is selected, the php function should show data of the current date but by treating it like a a selected date. It should treat the input date, weather it is the current date or a selected one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `ajax` call in a `function` and then `call` that function each time you select a **new** date.

To show the `current` OR `selected` date on **screen** you can use `.text` function display the date. As soon as the date page is loaded the ajax will be called and the current `date` data will `fetch` from `PHP`.

Lastly, once you do the `ajax` call you can show the `PHP` ajax data accordingly in your `success` function.

**Edit:** You can pass your `selecteddate` to this function as well => `showplannings(data.datecourante, data.message, selectedDate);` add a third `argument` in this function and receive this `third` argument in your `showplannings` function and do whatever is necessary.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#calendrier").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      //show selected on screen
      $('.selectedDate').text('Selected Date: ' + selectedDate)

      //call ajax on selected date
      myAjaxCall(selectedDate)
    }
  })
  //set date as current by default
  $("#calendrier").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

  //get date in a variable
  let currentDate = $('#calendrier').datepicker('getDate');
  let currentDateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", currentDate);

  //Show date on screen
  $('.selectedDate').text('Selected Date: ' + currentDateFormat)

  //Call ajax on load
  myAjaxCall(currentDateFormat) //pass current date to ajax function
});

//Ajax call
function myAjaxCall(selectedDate) {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://planning-ilm.atwebpages.com/userPlanning/' + selectedDate,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //let semaine = document.createTextNode('Sem du ' + data.datecourante.mday + '/' + data.datecourante.mon + '/' + data.datecourante.year);
      //$("#sem")[0].appendChild(semaine);
      //showplannings(data.datecourante, data.message, selectedDate);
                                                 //....^ - pass selected
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="calendrier"></p>

<p class="selectedDate"></p>

<button class="callAjax">Click Ajax</button>
```

Comment: @samaywise No problem - its a working code i have already tested this. Let me know if its all working and do not forget to accept the answer  :)

Comment: Can i use selectedDate passed by the URL to my php function (getUserPlanning) instead of getDate() method used in the function, so i can work with the selected date instead of the current date returned by getDate()?

Comment: @samaywise yes you can!!! Just do not call Ajax php on load. Please read the comments in my code and answer for each line of code. What you are asking is already working in my answer. It’s the Matter of choice when you wants to call php function let me know.

Comment: @samaywise what you are asking is already working in my asnwer. Please use the exact code I have provided.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is working, i am able to visualize correctly the data.datecourante and data.message when i type the Ajax URL on Web with the date. However, somehow it is not getting in showplannings(data.datecourante, data.datemessage) and getting in is crucial for my program, because it is where i am showing the planning of a user according to the date

Comment: @samaywise check my updated answer - You can pass your selected date to this function as well => `showplannings(data.datecourante, data.message, selectedDate);` add a third `argument` in this function and receive this third `argument` in your `showplannings` function and do whatever is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, i meant that showplanning is not getting triggered by the AJAX call, i dont need to pass selectedDate through it.

Comment: is the ajax request a success ? - if its successful then `showPlanning()` should run. Can you share a screenshot with me of you code.

Comment: @samaywise Where is `showPlanning()` function i can not see this function to be called in your code - please do not tell me you mixing up `jQuery` and `PHP` together please.

Comment: I updated my answer, there is the showplannings call

Comment: @samaywise that NOT a `showPlannning` function - please go through the jQuery code properly line by line and may be understand what each function is doing for you!!!!! **you are mixing up alot of things** - **you are calling a function (showPlannning) on success which does not exist at all.**

Comment: @samaywise thank you so much - thats what i want to see - Also are you sure that your ajax call returns a success - can you `console.log('hello')` inside the ajax success function and see what if that even works

Comment: It is not printing hello indeed, i put the console.log just above the showplannings call

Comment: I knew it ! You need to fix up ajax request. the URL is not working properly thats why its not to success function and that why it the `showPlanning()` never runs. Would you mind accepting my answer by clicking the grey checkmark in my answer since i have solved the original question already and helped as much as i could :)

Comment: Ok sure, but it is odd, when i type the Ajax url : [link] (http://planning-ilm.atwebpages.com/userPlanning/3/2020-09-21), i get the success values

Comment: the data from that URL is a text format you are trying to access it `dataType:json` - thats a total different issue to this question. I am not sure how to help on this question since according to stackoverflow we need a different question if the issue is different. As you know i have already helped enough from yesterday as much as i could. If this original question  is solved then please accept the answer. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the main function returning the success

```
   function getUserPlanning($url){
        // Get the user planning
        $today = $url[2];
        $nameOfDay = date('l', strtotime($today));
        // echo $nameOfDay;
        // echo $url[1];

        // If it's not Monday
        if($nameOfDay !== "Monday"){
            // (format : d-m-y)
            $monday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('previous monday', strtotime($today)));
            // $monday = getdate(strtotime("last Monday"));
            // echo("Monday : ".$monday. " ");
           
        
            //Getting all days in array
            $theWeek = currentWeek($monday);

            return $error = json_encode([
                'status' => 'ok',
                'datecourante' => $monday,
                'message' => getHisPlanning($url[1], $theWeek)
            ]);
        }
        else{
            // If already a monday is selected
            echo("ELSE today : ". $today);
            $theWeek = currentWeek($today);

            
            return $error = json_encode([
                'status' => 'ok',
                'datecourante' => $today,
                'message' => getHisPlanning($url[1], $theWeek)
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The function below is used in getUserPlanning for getting days in array

```
 function currentWeek($currentDate){
        // Get all weekdays in array
        $monday = strtotime($currentDate);
        $tuesday = strtotime("next Tuesday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $wednesday = strtotime("next Wednesday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $thursday = strtotime("next Thursday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $friday = strtotime("next Friday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $saturday = strtotime("next Saturday", strtotime($currentDate));
        $sunday = strtotime("next Sunday", strtotime($currentDate));

        // echo("Mardi".$tuesday);
        // echo("Mercredi".$wednesday);
        $week = [$monday, $tuesday, $wednesday, $thursday, $friday, $saturday, $sunday];
        return $week;
    }
```

This last function is what data.message should return

```
    function getHisPlanning($employe, $week){
        // Used to return the planning
        $weekPlanning = array(); 
        $connexion = connexion();
        echo("employé : " . $employe . " ");

        // Retrieving planning of each day for an employee
        for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
            // creating format y-m-d
            // echo($week[$i]);
            $dateCurrent = getdate($week[$i]);
            // echo($dateCurrent);
            $day = $dateCurrent['mday'];
            $month = $dateCurrent['mon'];
            $year = $dateCurrent['year'];

            // used in order to fetch date in db
            $jour = $year. '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
            echo("Jour : " . $jour . " ");

            // $request = $connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM plannings WHERE id_employe = ? AND date_planning = ? ORDER BY id_plage");
            $request = $connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM plannings INNER JOIN boutiques ON plannings.id_boutique = boutiques.id_boutique INNER JOIN affectations ON plannings.id_affectation = affectations.id_affectation WHERE id_employe = ? AND date_planning = ? ORDER BY id_plage");
            $request->execute(array($employe, $jour));

            // Stock planning of employee for each day
            $result = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Stock planning of week
            array_push($weekPlanning, $result);
        }
        return $weekPlanning;
    }
```

This is the Ajax call, user is an id and selectedDate the date selected

```
function AjaxCall(selectedDate, user){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url : 'http://planning-ilm.atwebpages.com/userPlanning/'+ user + '/' + selectedDate ,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data){
            // let semaine = document.createTextNode('Sem du ' + data.datecourante.mday + '/' + data.datecourante.mon + '/' + data.datecourante.year);
            // $("#sem")[0].appendChild(semaine);
            showplannings(data.datecourante, data.message);
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the showplannings call

```
$(function() {
  $("#calendrier").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      //show selected on screen
      $('.selectedDate').text('Selected Date: ' + selectedDate)

      //call ajax on selected date
      myAjaxCall(user, selectedDate)
    }
  })
  //set date as current by default
  $("#calendrier").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

  //get date in a variable
  let currentDate = $('#calendrier').datepicker('getDate');
  let currentDateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", currentDate);

  //Show date on screen
  $('.selectedDate').text('Selected Date: ' + currentDateFormat)

  //Call ajax on load
  myAjaxCall(user, currentDateFormat) //pass current date to ajax function
});

function myAjaxCall(user, selectedDate) {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://planning-ilm.atwebpages.com/userPlanning/' + '/' + user + '/' + selectedDate,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //let semaine = document.createTextNode('Sem du ' + data.datecourante.mday + '/' + data.datecourante.mon + '/' + data.datecourante.year);
      //$("#sem")[0].appendChild(semaine);
      showplannings(data.datecourante, data.message);
                                                
    }
  })
}
```